# ¿Como mandar form data con axios y vue js?

Tags: c#, vue.js

estoy tratando de enviar lo siguientes datos los cuales se muestran en un v-select, ya los datos como tal los tengo dentro de:

```
    const data = {
            id_usuario: this.$store.state.usuario.id_usuario,
            id_empresa: this.editedItem.id_empresa,
            id_TipoArchivo: this.editedItem.id_TipoArchivo,
            archivo: this.pdfs
        }
```

A través de axios.post, adjunto a la url 3 datos, los cuales son el id_usuario, id_empresa, y el id_TipoArchivo

```
      axios.post('http://localhost:55630/api/AppWeb/InsertaArchivos?Id_usuario=' + data.id_usuario + '&Id_empresa=' + data.id_empresa + '&Id_TipoArchivo=' + data.id_TipoArchivo

    lo que quiero hacer es enviar el formData en donde esta el archivo
```

Esta es la parte del código de mi back, esta hecho en c#

```
           [EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false)]
    [Route("api/AppWeb/InsertaArchivos")]
    public async Task<Reply> InsertaArchAsync([FromUri] ArchivosAppWebcon archivosweb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola si vas a mandar un post, para mandarlo con Axios seria algo asi

```
 Axios.post('tuapi', data).
   then((response) => {
   console.log(response)
   })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)}
    );
```

Siempre y cuando claro tu api tenga la estructura y el modelo como lo estas mandando.

Comment: Lo he probado y me regresa un error 500, y el API tiene esa estructura

Comment: Ahi no estas mandando un post si no un get con parametros,

Un post recibe por cuerpo un json

Seria de gran ayuda, si pusieras parte del codigo de tu backend

Comment: Adjunte un de como recibo la estructura en el API